# Python Recursion unique combination of 7 numbers in 6 digits

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make this work, and it does when the program is provided with exactly 7 numbers, but it fails once I increase to 8+. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The program is supposed to take 7+ numbers and output all 6 digit combinations of them using recursion.

Example input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 4 5 6 7
1 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Here's what I have.

```
def main():
    numbers = '1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34'
    numbers = numbers.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(lotto(numbers))):
        print(lotto(numbers)[i])

def lotto(numbers):
    if len(numbers) < 7:
        return numbers
    else:
        output = list()
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            rem = lotto(numbers[i+1:])
            output.append(numbers[:i]+rem)
    return output
```

When I put in 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 as shown above,

```
['1', '3', '5', '8', '13', '21', '34']
['1', '2', '5', '8', '13', '21', '34']
['1', '2', '3', '8', '13', '21', '34']
['1', '2', '3', '5', '13', '21', '34']
['1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '21', '34']
['1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '13', '34']
['1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '13', '21']
```

Is the output, rather than

```
1 2 3 5 8 13
1 2 3 5 8 21
1 2 3 5 8 34
1 2 3 5 13 21
1 2 3 5 13 34
1 2 3 5 21 34
1 2 3 8 13 21
1 2 3 8 13 34
1 2 3 8 21 34
1 2 3 13 21 34
1 2 5 8 13 21
1 2 5 8 13 34
1 2 5 8 21 34
1 2 5 13 21 34
1 2 8 13 21 34
1 3 5 8 13 21
1 3 5 8 13 34
1 3 5 8 21 34
1 3 5 13 21 34
1 3 8 13 21 34
1 5 8 13 21 34
2 3 5 8 13 21
2 3 5 8 13 34
2 3 5 8 21 34
2 3 5 13 21 34
2 3 8 13 21 34
2 5 8 13 21 34
3 5 8 13 21 34
```

The problem isn't the list vs no list output, it's the number and size of the output.

Comment: What do you mean by `fails`?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Edited for clarity, I hope

Answer (score 1):

Python already has this function built-in: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

```
g = permutations('1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34'.split())
for v in g:
    print " ".join(v)
```

Here is sample output:

```
34 21 13 8 2 1 3 5
34 21 13 8 2 1 5 3
34 21 13 8 2 3 1 5
34 21 13 8 2 3 5 1
34 21 13 8 2 5 1 3
34 21 13 8 2 5 3 1
```

Comment: I want to input 7+ numbers, but have the result be only 6 characters. I also have to use recursion.

Comment: @user3018875 Well, use the python built-in is the best solution because the function is tested and fast. But if it is a homework question I don't think I am of much help here. You should add the 'homework' tag in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use a `''.join(list)`

```
>>> x = 'hello world'
>>> x = list(x)
>>> x
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> ''.join(x)
'hello world'
>>>
```